# Adding jar created using ant build with antrun plugin to maven build dependencies

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-antrun-plugin

- I am having multiple projects which are using ant for build management. Now we have created a new project which uses Maven for build management.
- Since the new project which uses maven has dependency on projects which are built using ant.
- I was able to integrate the build of individual projects in the current maven build using maven antrun plugin

```
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>deploy-artifact</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <ant antfile="../project1/build.xml" inheritAll="false">
                                    <target name="dist"/>
                                </ant>
                                <ant antfile="../project2/build.xml" inheritAll="false">
                                    <target name="dist"/>
                                </ant>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
                        <version>1.4.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ant-commons-net</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
                        <version>1.5.0</version>
                        <scope>system</scope>
                        <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

- The issue which I am facing now is that when the build for project1 and project2 are complete I want the jar generated using ant dist target to be used as dependency in the current maven build.
- maven build for current project is breaking since it looks for project1 and project2 jars at compilation time but they are missing. I want the builds for project1 and project2 to be triggered within the current maven build and dependencies not to be added using external command line mvn:install:install-file

---

Any suggestions/solutions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

All dependencies of a Maven build need to exist *before* the build starts. They are resolved at the very beginning of the build.